# GridSearch with XGBoost producing Depreciation error on infinite loop

Tags: performance, machine-learning, xgboost, grid-search, hyperparameters

I am trying to do a hyperparameter tuning using GridSearchCV on XGBoost.But, I'm getting the following error.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py:151: DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous. Returning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use `array.size > 0` to check that an array is not empty.if diff:
```

This keeps on running forever. Given below is the code.

```
    classifier = xgb.XGBClassifier()

    from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
    n_estimators=[10,50,100,150,200,250,300]
    max_depth=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    learning_rate=[0.1,0.01,0.09,0.08,0.07,0.001]
    colsample_bytree=[0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]
    min_child_weight=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    gamma=[0.001,0.01,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,1]
    subsample=[0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]

    param_grid=dict(n_estimators=n_estimators,max_depth=max_depth,learning_rate=learning_rate,colsample_bytree=colsample_bytree,min_child_weight=min_child_weight,gamma=gamma,subsample=subsample)

   grid = GridSearchCV(classifier, param_grid, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
   grid.fit(X, Y)
   grid.grid_scores_

   print(grid.best_score_)
   print(grid.best_params_)
   print(grid.best_estimator_)

   # Predicting the Test set results
   Y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

   # Making the Confusion Matrix
   from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
   cm = confusion_matrix(Y_test, Y_pred)
```

I am using python3.5, XGBOOT and gridsearch library has already been preloaded. I am running this on google collaboratory.

Please suggest what is going wrong ?

Comment: Its just a warning. It wont affect your results in anyway. And you cant do anything here. Its coming from `sklearn` and will be fixed in next coming version.